# Electrically rewiring cells into series or parallel, BMS decision

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I was thinking about making a battery pack that would alow me to select two voltages by electrically switching (via transistors) two parallel 5S battery packs into one 10S battery pack. It offers me a better efficiency than switched regulator.

But I don't know if I should use one 10S BMS or two 5S BMS? What if I would like to connect together three packs of cells? Three separate 5S BMS? I would like to charge the whole battery pack(2x or 3x 5S together) with a 5S charger.

Any suggestions or help is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is max current ? Will a transistor support that?

Comment: if the 10S BMS you have in mind has a specific 2x5S mode, then use that. However, a 10S BMS is likely to be damaged by connecting it 2x5S. Go with what the modularity is telling you, use a 5S BMS on a 5S pack of cells, and switch series/parallel at the module level.